# What is the equivalent of # compiz --replace in lubuntu?

Tags: compiz, window-manager, openbox, lubuntu

What is the equivalent of this command in lubuntu?

```
# compiz --replace
```

Comment: are you trying to start compiz, if so install it. Then type what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compiz` is the window manager used by Unity. Running `compiz --replace` when Unity is running will start a new instance of the window manager, replacing the old instance.

Lubuntu uses the `openbox` window manager. So if you want to do is to run a new instance of `openbox`, replacing the old one, run:

```
openbox --replace
```

That's probably what you want.

On the other hand, if you want to replace `openbox` *with `compiz`*, just run `compiz --replace`. (If that doesn't work, try killing `openbox` manually first with `killall openbox`.)

**By the way, you've written `compiz --replace` with a `#` character in front of it, as though you're running it from a root shell. That would be wrong. `compiz`, `openbox`, and other window managers should be run as the non-root user who is graphically logged in, *not* as root. Do *not* use `sudo` to run `compiz` or `openbox`.**

Comment: $ openbox --replace

Comment: that was just an error, i only run it from Alt+F2 run box :)